# Could not find HelloCordova-CordovaLib.apk

Tags: eclipse, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I installed the latest version of cordova(3.4) on my windows computer successfully.
But when I run the the built the project using eclipse and run it, the following error occurred saying :
Could not find HelloCordova-CordovaLib.apk
which prevent me to use cordova API.
note that "HelloCordova" is the project name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and find the solution. Can you check the following:

- Right-click then Properties of your HelloCordova-CordovaLib project: in the "Android" tab, check that the "IsLibrary" checkbox is checked
- Right-click then Properties of your HelloCordova project: in "Android" tab, "IsLibrary" must not be checked and your CordovaLib must be listed in the array under this checkbox + in "Java Build Path" tab", under "Projects", the "HelloCordova-CordovaLib" project must not be referenced.

Then clean and rebuild your solution, it should be working